# How to change a rails controller default router from index to other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, indexing, router

As we know, if we have a `UsersController`, when we get `/users` it default to `/users/index`. If I want to map `/users` to `/users/show`, what can I do? (This can apply to any other controllers, not just users.)

Answer (score 0):

You can modified the file Global.asax.
There is a method named 'RegisterRoutes',change the 'Index' in 'action=Index' to 'show'

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between URLs for the `index` action and the `show` action is the `show` action requires the identity of the resource. The default Rails URL for `index` on the users resource is `/users`, and the default `show` URL looks like `/users/12`, where the 12 identifies the resource. This identification part isn't optional, so you can't usefully map `/users` to the show action in a RESTful scheme.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to have a profile page at localhost:3000/username you can add `match '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :user` to routes.rb and `<%= link_to "Profile", @user %>` to your view. With a little fiddling in the controller to grab your profile info via the current user's username, this will link to localhost:3000/username.